# Finding a dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**
$V$ is a vector space over $F$, Let $ T\colon V \to V$

$U=\{S \in \operatorname{Hom}(V,V): S \circ T=0\}$.
$\dim V=2$.
If $\dim\operatorname{Im} T=1$ what is $\dim U$?

**Thoughts**:
Tried to translate it somehow to a product of matrices, but didn't really know how to use the fact about the rank (how to build the matrices in a way I'll be able to figure the dimension of $U$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Note that $U$ can be identified with the space of linear functions from the $1$-dimensional space $V/\operatorname{Im} T$ to $V$.

Comment: Thanks. But why can't S get vectors that are not in ImT as well?